# Does IntelliJ IDEA have a Create Wrapper code generator

Tags: java, code-generation, intellij-idea

If I have an interface with a few methods.  Sometimes I need to create a new implementation of the interface which wraps another instance of the interface and delegates most of the methods to the wrapped instance.  Then I would change a couple of the implementations, maybe not delegating them.

A classic example would be the `Collections.unmodifiableXXX()` methods in the JDK which block access to the modification methods.

Does IntelliJ have any code assistance that will generate a delegate implementation of the interface and then I can just tweak a couple of methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do it in two stages. First implement the interface and then introduce delegation

Comment: Thanks.  To be clear the steps are..  1) Implement interface. 2) Add target member variable that is being delegated to.  3) Use Code|Delegate and first select the member variable target and then all the methods you want delegated.

Comment: Thank you so very, very, VERY much.

Answer (score 16):

`Code|Delegate Methods`

Comment: This is useful to delegate based on a field member rather than a base class

Comment: This refactoring can also be accessed from Alt+Enter menu.

Comment: @Jonathan Neufeld when you override methods, call to base class implementation is inserted by default.