# private final composition mapping generation macro in Intellij Idea or Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, refactoring, intellij-idea

*I find that I need to frequently favor composition over inheritance and consequently a lot of the lines of code I need to produce are made of the mappings between the `private final Contract implementation` and the `Contract` interface methods.*

#### (Predictable) Mapping Example

```
public abstract class Sloth<T> extends BaseAnimal implements Valuator<T> {

    private final Valuator<T> valuator = new GenericValuator<T>();

    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) {
        valuator.setValue(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearValue() {
        valuator.clearValue();
    }

    @Override
    public T getDefault() {
        return valuator.getDefault();
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return valuator.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void addStorageBidListeners(OnStorageBid<T>... onStorageBid) {
        valuator.addStorageBidListeners(onStorageBid);
    }

}
```

---

Is there any way to **auto-generate** this mapping:

- In principle it should suffice to just supply the interface and the implementation?
- At the moment I'm manually writing out all the `valuator.` mappings, Im hoping there is a shortcut to such automatic refactoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Alt + Ins` then select `Delegate methods..`

In first step you should select your property. In your example is it valuator.
In next step choose methods.

Comment: i had trouble getting to enable the `Delegate Methods..` option and in the end discovered that it would NOT work if the caret was on the field (e.g. `valuator`) nor if I selected the field - the cursor had to be anywhere but (within the body of the class)...

Comment: now found more of same question as well, using synonymous terminology [Can IntelliJ automatically create a decorator class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325699/can-intellij-automatically-create-a-decorator-class) and [Does IntelliJ IDEA have a Create Wrapper code generator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753349/does-intellij-idea-have-a-create-wrapper-code-generator)